# Pandas. считать стоблец xml как str

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pandas, excel

Нужно преобразовать столбец, который, как я понимаю, int64, в строковый тип. Если в `pandas.read_excel("example.xlsx", dtype = {"col":str})`, то в `pandas.read_xml` какой параметр за это отвечает?

Comment: Судя по документации, для xml такого нет. А что мешает преобразовать _после_ чтения файла?

Comment: я думаю, что он обнулит последние цифры, но сейчас попробую

Comment: В принципе, лучше, чем предполагал, но не совсем то, получается вид типа "5849240882000496.0", избавиться бы от этого .0 (я использовал astype)

Comment: Вангую, что в столбце есть `NaN`, поэтому он превратился в `float`, нужно устранять первопричину. И покажите ваше преобразование.

Comment: Так и есть, первая строка, но я её вроде как удалил перед преобразованием, получилось так: `xmll= xmll.drop(index=[0])
xmll = xmll.astype({"COL":str})`